# Spinner does not get selected after setting adapter

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have two spinner in dialog. Second one is dependent on first one. I want to bind it and then select it in edit mode. All works fine but second spinner does not get selected. However it get selected when I open my dialog next time.
Here is a part of my code.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdap1 = (ArrayAdapter<String>) spnForeignKeyTable
                        .getAdapter();
                int spinnerPosition1 = myAdap1.getPosition(objcolumn_schema
                        .getForeignKeyTable());
                spnForeignKeyTable.setSelection(spinnerPosition1);
                // Bind Column Spinner.Second spinner

                dblist = DBAdapter.getColumns(pf.getString("dbid", ""),String.valueOf(objcolumn_schema.getForeignKeyTableID()));
                ArrayAdapter<String> adpf = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        column.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        dblist);
                adpf.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spnForeignKeyColumn.setAdapter(adpf);


                int spinnerPosition2 = adpf.getPosition(objcolumn_schema.getForeignKey());
                spnForeignKeyColumn.setSelection(spinnerPosition2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for changing selected item in second spinner when first spinner selection change you will need to set `setOnItemSelectedListener` for first spinner as:

```
spinnerPosition1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, 
                                                     int position, long id)
        {
           // change second Spinner selection here
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
            //
        }
    });
```